# MS Outlook 2007 <br> Problem

Tags: html, css, outlook-2007

I've made a HTMLemailer for a client. The emailer has a few line breaks with it. On other clients it looks perfect, until i come across MS Outlook 2007. Outlook doesnt seem to recognize the `<br>` and the width that iset inside a `<div>`. Is there a fix for this? Thanks in advance.

```
<table width="602px" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
            <p align="center" style="font-family: arial; font-size: 11px; color: #000000;">If you are unable to read the contents of this email, please <b><a href="#" style="color:#000000; text-decoration:none;">click here</a></b> to view the online version.</p>
            <br>
         </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3"><a href="#"><img src="#" width="602" height="161" alt="#"></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3" style="border-top:2px black solid;"><br><br></td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using div's in email html, use tables instead. `<br>`'s should work tho. Could you post some code?

Comment: there you go. i updated the post with the code. there's a <br><br> there.

Comment: To my knowledge, a `<br />` is ignored if there is no additional content to break. Maybe try adding a `&nbsp;` after your line-breaks and see if the result is what you're expecting? (Plus, I don't hold much faith to Outlook's rendering as it uses MS Office's engine instead of IE).

Comment: @Brad Christie - that worked man! thanks for the tip and explanation.

Comment: @user: Not a problem, glad to help. ;-)

Comment: @BradChristie you should put your suggestion as an answer, so we can upvote it. :) Credit where credit is due.

Comment: @BradChristie Your comment is the right answer for this question. Please consider making it into an answer not just for the credits as you thoroughly deserve it, but especially for future users!

Comment: @purple11111 done. I'm just glad i could help. Cheers!

Answer (score 5):

Outlook is a pain for most things HTML email. You could try self closing the br tag `<br />`, and maybe putting it inside the paragraph element, but I doubt it'll get it working on its own. Other things I'd try are to add a none breaking space `&nbsp;` character to force some kind of layout into the td cell, or even going proper old-school and inserting a white padding image with the height set to whatever you need.

Comment: Replacing "Text<br><br>" with "<p>Text</p>" worked fine for me in Outlook 2007.

Answer (score 1):

*Converting comment to answer, as this was just brought to my attention:*

To my knowledge, a `<br />` is ignored if there is no additional content to break. Maybe try adding a `&nbsp;` after your line-breaks and see if the result is what you're expecting? (Plus, I don't hold much faith to Outlook's rendering as it uses MS Office's engine instead of IE).

Answer (score 1):

```
<br>&nbsp;
```

Put 2 lines instead 1.

So I made a component called "br"

```
<table><tr><td>&nbsp;</table></tr></td
```

Works in all email clients

Comment: Your code is too broken to even figure out what you are trying to say.

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from declaring `<br>` in a new line. Outlook automatically adds a new line plus the `br`. Try putting them in the same line as the previous code.

Comment: I am doing <br/> on the same line as my code and it does not fix this issue.

Answer (score -1):

Aside from the suggestions already made, I would recommend using some of the HTML newsletter creators that are available these days;

- [Mosaic](https://mosaico.io/)
- [Publicate](https://publicate.it)

I know from my company Publicate, we spend a large amount of time testing and optimising the HTML so that it can be exported and renders correctly in Outlook.

We use Email on Acid as part of the testing process, which might be helpful to you too, or also check out Litmus if you are wanting to code your own.